# using immlib for API hooking Python gives Error

Tags: python, reverse-engineering

I am trying to do simple API hooking using immunity debugger, now i followed this tutorial from here http://c0defreak.blogspot.com/2013/03/sniffing-data-before-its-gets-encryted.html and i saved the python script in the pycommands folder and when i ran the command, i am getting this as error

```
Unable to read memory of debugged process. Breakpoint at FFFFFFFF is deleted.
```

Please What do i appear to be missing?

**Edit**

The code i am using to test looks thus

```
from immlib import *

class fire (LogBpHook) :
          def __init__(self):
                   self.imm=Debugger();
                   self.logfile = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ff_log.txt"
#directory where the log file has to be saved
                   LogBpHook.__init__(self)

          def run(self,regs):
                   addr=self.imm.readLong(regs['ESP']+8)
                   str=self.imm.readString(addr)
                   self.imm.log("PR_Write ( 0x%x) <- %s" % (addr,str) )
                   fd = open( self.logfile, "a" )
                   fd.write( str )
                   fd.close()
# this function run automatically when hook is hit and function code is #executed which logs it in to file and displays on log window of debugger

def main(args) :
          imm=Debugger()
          wfun=imm.getAddress("nss3.PR_Write")
#setup hook point
          fire_hook=fire()
          fire_hook.add( "%08x" % wfun, wfun)
          return "[*] READY for ACTION"
```

I have clicked the Play button and tried to logon to the form from the firefox browser it does not show in immunity debugger neither does it show in the textfile.

Comment: Can you post the code for the script you're running here?

Comment: @wogsland, Edited , Kindly see Edits.